# Sorting/Grouping SQL by day-of-week and hour-of-day

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by, utc

I have a SQL Server 2005 table that contains records with a UTC/GMT date field.
I need to have the records GROUPed BY and ORDERed by the "day of the week" and "hour of the day".  Giving 7*24=168 groups.  The output would look like:

```
Sun 12am
Sun  1am
Sun  2am
.... etc
Mon 12am
Mon  1am
.... etc
.... etc
Sat 10pm
Sat 11pm
```

Everything works fine until I try to convert things to my local time zone. 
Doing the conversion inside SQL:

```
SELECT MIN(Key),MIN(SavedOn), 
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY (DatePart(WEEKDAY, SavedOn)*24.0) + DatePart(HOUR, SavedOn) - (5.0/24.0)
ORDER BY (DatePart(WEEKDAY, SavedOn)*24.0) + DatePart(HOUR, SavedOn) - (5.0/24.0)
```

Or doing the conversion in my own code AFTER sorting/getting the records in UTC:

```
SELECT MIN(Key),MIN(SavedOn), 
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY (DatePart(WEEKDAY, SavedOn)*24.0) + DatePart(HOUR, SavedOn)  
ORDER BY (DatePart(WEEKDAY, SavedOn)*24.0) + DatePart(HOUR, SavedOn) 

(my own math here)
```

Either way... 5 records will appear "out of order".   The end of the week records (Sat PM)
appear at the beginning of the week... not the end... where they belong.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Floating point math is imprecise.  Multiplying by `24.0` invites border errors.

Instead of adding the numbers

```
GROUP BY (DatePart(WEEKDAY, SavedOn)*24.0) + DatePart(HOUR, SavedOn)
```

sort on two fields instead:

```
GROUP BY DatePart(WEEKDAY, SavedOn), DatePart(HOUR, SavedOn)
```

Comment: But multiplying is now what causes the errors, is it? I thought it was the converting to Eastern time, or whatever TZ, that OP is doing. No?

Comment: What would my "ORDER BY" line be, in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do. I am not sure I totally understand what you are trying though:

```
SELECT DatePart(WEEKDAY, SavedOn), DatePart(HOUR, SavedOn) , min(key)
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY DatePart(WEEKDAY, SavedOn), DatePart(HOUR, SavedOn)
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

If your approach to converting is just to add 5 hours, then do it every time you see `SavedOn` , like this:

```
SELECT DatePart(WEEKDAY, SavedOn+5.0/24.0), DatePart(HOUR, SavedOn+5.0/24.0) , min(key)
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY DatePart(WEEKDAY, SavedOn+5.0/24.0, DatePart(HOUR, SavedOn+5.0/24.0)
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: I'll be more than happy to fix my original post.  Which part is unclear?

Comment: I tried your solution... and it still returns some "Sat PM" groups... and then afterwards... returns "Sun AM".   I need them sorted as shown in my list... Sun... Mon... Tue... etc.   NOT Sat.. Sun... Mon... etc

Comment: @Carol - even with the 5/24 added everywhere? I think I've done this before and it works. Can you confirm that the above is what you tried?